# best way to generate long SQLite statements for a pivot

Tags: sql, sqlite, pivot

I need to create very long SQLite statements, pivots outputting thousands of columns.

I've resorted to doing this using string manipulation.

Just wondering if the SQLite API has a more elegant solution.

Example of desired output:

```
str = "SELECT sample_id
        , SUM(CASE WHEN gear_id = 1 THEN counts ELSE 0 END) AS g1
        , SUM(CASE WHEN gear_id = 2 THEN counts ELSE 0 END) AS g2

        ...

        , SUM(CASE WHEN gear_id = N THEN counts ELSE 0 END) AS gN
       FROM table1 GROUP BY sample_id"
```

Comment: You can generate the statement programmatically, with the tool of your choice... Where to the list of columns come from?

Comment: Thanks, yeah the above works fine, the list of columns is just unique(gear_id) from the example above.